# IOS Storyboard Flow and UITableView Reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

Newer to IOS developent and I'm wondering what the best way would be to transition between views in the storyboard with dynamic editable content that has the exact same UITableView the only difference is the header/title.

It's kind of like a multi-page form but all the questions are the same just the page/title changes.

I'm thinking I reuse the UITableView for each set of questions but I'd like it to swipe from question set to question set. I could use a push back to itself?

(I'm also trying to attempt it in swift)

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like it's just one pair of view controllers with a segue connecting them.  The second vc (the one with the changing title) can have an NSString property indicating its title.  Set that on prepareForSegue in the first vc, based on the selection that gets you there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would those 2 VC's just loop? In the ends it would be 10 vc's.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned, it could use a navigation controller and push another instance of itself, just changing the model on the new instance each step.  Or you could have user flip back to the start vc, then press a button to continue.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info I'm not sure why I didn't think of trying that.